# Match first dt and first dd, not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to match every child, but not the first dd and first dd element:

```
<dl class="aaa">
   <dd>...</dd>
   <dt>...</dt>
</dl>
```

Css:

```
.aaa dd:not(:first-child),
.aaa dt:not(:first-child) {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

With the above CSS, only `dd` will match, the first dt will have the margin-top attribute applied.

I think I'm using `first-child` wrong here?

Comment: You seem to have your `<dt>` and `<dd>` the wrong way around; the `<dt>` is the term to be defined, the `<dd>` is the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class instead of `:first-child`.

`:first-child` refers to *any element* that is the first child of its parent, whereas `:first-of-type` represents the first element *of its type* among all children of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

```css
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aaa dd:not(:first-of-type),
.aaa dd + dt:not(:first-of-type) {
   background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<dl class="aaa">
   <dd>DD</dd>
   <dt>DT</dt>
    
    <dd>DD</dd>
   <dt>DT</dt>
    
    <dd>DD</dd>
   <dt>DT</dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the general sibling (`~`) combinator, to target all `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements that are subsequent siblings of a `<dt>` and `<dd>`:

```
.aaa dt ~ dt,
.aaa dd ~ dd {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```js
// Just for numbering the <dt> and <dd> elements.
$('dt').text(function(i) {
  return 'Term ' + i;
});

$('dd').text(function(i) {
  return 'Definition ' + i;
});
```

```css
.aaa dt ~ dt,
.aaa dd ~ dd {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="aaa">
  <dt></dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt></dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt></dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt></dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt></dt>
  <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

This is because in your posted code:

```
.aaa dd:not(:first-child),
.aaa dt:not(:first-child) {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The selector for `<dt>` can't match any element, given that the `<dt>` isn't the `:first-child` of its parent.